# Designing custom workflow in JAVA and Spring

Tags: java, oop, spring-boot, design-patterns, web-application-design

I am working on an spring 2.0.1.RELEASE application.

> **Brief of Application:**

```
1. I have separate Transformer beans that transforms my DTO to Domain
and vice versa.
2. I have separate Validator beans that validate my domain object being passed.
3. I have Service classes that takes care of the applying rules and calling persistence layer.
```

---

> Now, i want to build a **Workflow** in my application:
>   where i will just call the start of the workflow and below mentioned steps will be executed in order and exception handling will be done as per the step:

```
1.First-Transformtion - transformToDomain() method will be called for that object type.  
2.Second-Validator - class valid() method will be called for that object.  
3.Third-Service - class save() method will be called for that object.  
4.Fourth- Transformation - transformToDTO() method will be called for that object type.
```

after this my workflow ends and i will return the DTO object as response of my REST API.

Exception handling part is the one, i also want to take care of, like if particular exception handler exist for that step then call it, else call global exception handler.

I designed some prototype of same, but looking for some expert advice and how this can be achieved with a better design in java.

---

**Explanation with example considering above use case is highly appreciable.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Brief** of what i implemented in a way with not much hustle:

[image: This is my design classes]

### This is how I created flow of handlers:

```
Stream.<Supplier<RequestHandler>>of(
            TransformToDomainRequestHandler::new,
            ValidateRequestHandler::new,
            PersistenceHandler::new,
            TransformToDTORequestHandler::new)
            .sequential()
            .map(c -> c.get()) /* Create the handler instance */
            .reduce((processed, unProcessed) -> { /* chains all handlers together */
                RequestHandler previous = processed;
                RequestHandler target = previous.getNextRequestHandler();
                while (target != null && previous != null) {
                    previous = target;
                    target = target.getNextRequestHandler();
                }
                previous.setNextRequestHandler(unProcessed);
                return processed;
            }).get();
```

[image: This is my Workflow State container]

This is my Request Handler which all other handler extends

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure if what you are describing is a workflow system in its true sense, perhaps a **Chain of Responsibility** is more of what you are talking about?

Following what you described as a sequence of execution, here is a simplified example of how I would implement the chain:

Transformer.java

```
public interface Transformer<IN, OUT> {

  OUT transformToDomain(IN dto);

  IN transformToDTO(OUT domainObject);
}
```

Validator.java

```
public interface Validator<T> {

  boolean isValid(T object);
}
```

Service.java

```
public interface Service {

  void save(Object object);
}
```

And the implementation that binds everything:
ProcessChain.java

```
public class ProcessChain {

  private Transformer transformer;
  private Service service;
  private Validator validator;

  Object process(Object dto) throws MyValidationException {
    Object domainObject = transformer.transformToDomain(dto);
    boolean isValid = validator.isValid(domainObject);
    if(!isValid){
      throw new MyValidationException("Validation message here");
    }
    service.save(domainObject);
    return transformer.transformToDTO(domainObject);
  }
}
```

I haven't specified any Spring related things here because your question seems to be a design question rather than a technology questions.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate you got my question correctly. your answer seems to be very simple, in real world things won't be that easy, like if we have 20 transformer for each domain object, 20 validators and 20 services for each type of resource object, so we need to call respective transformer, validator and service method and if we do the same in the way you described above, will lose the ultimate purpose of implementing the design (i.e lose coupling). i earlier achieved this using the way you suggested, to me it seems more like a facade that is hiding complexity. wat do u say?

Comment: Somehow, separation of responsibility adds loss coupling and low maintenance cost with effective exception handling for separate handlers.
I will post the brief of the design I have finally implemented in this using Chain Of Responsibility, Observer, Strategy, Generics and some power of the Spring. Kindly have a look at my answer, tomorrow i will post it, suggest me if something can be done in a better way. I am looking for best way to achieve this.

Comment: Agreed, this will get messy real quick for a sizeable application especially if there's a DTO for every Domain Object. The DTOs are built in anticipation of the required representation of data and not your full domain so this would mean you actually have fewer DTOs to map and some DTOs will have data from more than one Domain Object.

Comment: So Loose Coupling may be the objective however, High Cohesion needs to be maintained. For me, if the process of fulfilling your request involves all of this, then it seems inevitable that you would end up with this structure (in some way or another)

Comment: I posted brief of what i have implemented, if you can suggest anything on it. then is really appreciable.

Comment: @SahilVerma your implementation seems fine to me, especially since I have very little insight into what you are working towards. It also seems that there is no getting away from having a transformer for every DTO, etc.